# MAC Address - Privacy

Tags: network-programming, mac-address, privacy

I wrote a program which checks for updates on my server, but I want every request to be logged on the server.

Therefore I want to see which request belongs to which computer, I want to use the MAC address for this task.

Now my question, if my program sends its MAC address to the server and it's logged there, would this be a violation of privacy? I mean is it allowed that my application reads out the MAC address (from an external computer which is not mine) and sends it to my server?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for legal advice rather than programming help.

Comment: @DonRoby, I think it also has a technical aspect: whether a MAC address can be used to identify a device. It depends on how the question is done.

Answer (score 0):

With a MAC address you can uniquely identify a device as, from factory, every network interface has a unique MAC address. Of course, there are especial cases where you can modify the MAC address in a device but this is not for the normal user.

Said this, it is your call if you want to send and keep this data or not. I'd recommend not doing it unless you have explicit opt-in from the user.